# Handle user interaction in application

Tags: swift, swift3, user-interaction

In my application I use this when I want to disable the user interaction:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

But how does the above row differ from:

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Is it any rules of when to use some of the rows above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` works on an individual `UIView` where as `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` includes the whole `UIWindow` meaning that iterations on `UINavigationBar` are not included in `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled`.

If you are trying to suspend User interaction while you are performing some UI action like drawing or animating and don't want user to interrupt the process you should be using `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()`.

If you are trying to restrict interactions on a single `UIView` like say a ````` UILabel```` or a `````UIImage``` then you should be going with `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`.

Hope that helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: glad it helped.